# Does Android support an interceptor like pattern? Want to catch all 403 responses before main logic

Tags: java, android, error-handling, client-server, interceptor

I'm making an android app which communicates alot thru HTTP / JSON for populating different views in the GUI.

I have:

- Made a login screen and the main views
- A server which trows HTTP 403 if you request a login protected resourse / mainly JSON.

I want:

- An interseptor like concept which can set the view/activity to the login screen if 403 is encountered.

The rationale for this is so I don't have to make an explicit 403 error handling in all my AsyncTasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't have anything like this.

The best solution would be to create a utility method that handles the HTTP connection, and either returns the `HttpResponse`, or does the error handling on 403, and use that method everywhere in your code to connect to your server, instead of building `HttpClients` in every `AsyncTask` by hand.